# Why is the Skyscraper Sheaf defined as it is?

Tags: abstract-algebra, sheaf-theory

In Vakil's Foundations of Algebraic Geometry he defines the skyscraper sheaf as follows.

Let $X$ be a topological space with $p\in X$.  Let $S$ be a set and $\{e\}$ any singleton set.  Let $i_p:p\to X$ be the inclusion then define:
$$
i_{p,_{*}S}(U) =
\begin{cases}
S,& p\in U\\
\{e\},& p\not\in U
\end{cases}
$$

My question is, is there any reason why we use a single-element set $\{e\}$?
As far as I can tell, we still get a sheaf if we use an arbitrary set  in place of $\{e\}$.  Why don't we use, say, the empty set instead?

Comment: In practice you'll be working with sheaves of abelian groups and then $\{ e \}$ is the trivial group. Skyscraper sheaves are supposed to look like skyscrapers: really tall at one point, and nonexistent everywhere else. They're the analogue in sheaf theory of Dirac delta functions, so they're supposed to be "zero" everywhere except at one point, namely $p$.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan I believe when $X$ is not $T_1$ sky scraper sheafs can have stalks at other points than $x$ if $x$ is not a closed point, then any element in the closure will have non zero stalk.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a simple pragmatic reason that you can't use the empty set in place of $\{e\}$, at least when $S$ is nonempty: If $i_{p,*}S(X) = S$, then for any open set $U$, there is a restriction map $\rho^X_U\colon S\to i_{p,*}S(U)$, so $i_{p,*}S(U)$ cannot be empty.

As for why the definition is as it is, the skyscraper sheaf satisfies a universal property: The stalk of $i_{p,*}X$ at $p$ is $S$, and for any other sheaf $F$ on $X$ such that $F_p = S$, there is a unique sheaf morphism $F\to i_{p,*}S$ such that the induced map $F_p \to (i_{p,*}S)_p$ is the identity map on $S$. That is, the skyscraper sheaf is terminal in the category of sheaves on $X$ with stalk $S$ at $p$ (where the morphisms are those which induce the identity map on $S$). The appearance of the singleton set $\{e\}$ can be explained by the fact that $\{e\}$ is the terminal object in $\mathsf{Set}$.

This universal property is a bit awkward to state, since the uniqueness of the map $F\to i_{p,*}S$ depends on an identification of the stalk of $F$ at $p$ with $S$. It's cleaner to view it as a special case of the fact (it's a good exercise, and I'd be surprised if it's not in Vakil's notes) that the skyscraper sheaf at $p$ functor $i_{p,*}\colon \mathsf{Set}\to \mathsf{Sh}(X)$ is right adjoint to to the stalk at $p$ functor $(-)_p\colon \mathsf{Sh}(X)\to \mathsf{Set}$. Then the canonical map in the previous paragraph is the image of the identity map on $S$ under the natural isomorphism $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{Set}}(F_p,S)\to \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{Sh}(X)}(F,i_{p,*}S)$. To put it another way, it's the component $\eta_F$ at $F$ of the unit of this adjunction $\eta\colon \text{id}_{\mathsf{Sh}(X)} \to i_{p,*}(-)_p$.

This answer was in terms of sheaves of sets, but the same things are true for sheaves of abelian groups, modules, etc. as mentioned in Qiaochu's comment.

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed answer.  I am still a beginner at sheaf theory.  I'll need to spend more time working through the details in the second part of your answer, but I think I can see how it works.

Comment: I don’t know if I agree with the first paragraph, although you probably know more about this than I do, but that restriction map need only be a morphism, not necessarily a function. It seems one could just define that morphism appropriately to satisfy the axioms and use the empty set.

Comment: @PrinceM Sure, you can define the notion of "sheaf with values in C" for any category C, which would allow you to decide what counts as a morphism. But the question is about a sheaf with values in the category of sets. In the category of sets, morphisms are functions, and there is no function from a nonempty set to the empty set.

Comment: Good point! I guess since OP didn’t mention the category $/textbf{Set}$ specifically I was thinking they were taking values in any category that had sets as objects. I have a couple sheaf related questions that aren’t really worthy of posting a question here on stack exchange (they are more soft questions / intuition related). I see your email is on your faculty page and sheafs were a big component of your qualifying exam. Would you mind if I sent you an email? I don’t expect any urgency for a response

Comment: @PrinceM I think it's better to ask here. Questions about intuition are on topic, and you'll be able to get multiple perspectives.

Comment: I just despise dealing with comments telling me my question isn’t well defined since there’s not ‘one right answer’. Particularly, I would like to ask about the sky scraper sheaf is called sky scraper, and how I am interpreting why it’s called that. I am just beginning to learn sheafs and I like to discuss informal things like this to make sure I am thinking about objects in the “canonical” way, because a lot of times it turns out I am not. I will post as soon as I get to my office (on my phone right now). I look forward to an answer from you if you happen to have time!